# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' for Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to run a code. It is written in Python3 using Tensorflow. I could run the code, but when the code was running, I tried to run another code with some changes in a separate Anaconda Prompt. Then I stopped the code. Now, when I try to run the similar code again without any changes, it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The error refers to the tensorflow\python\keras package as follow:

```
hdf5_format.py. line 711, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
```

This is some parts of my code which rises the error:

```
self.encoder.load_weights(weights_file, by_name = True)
```

I closed the program and reopened it, but the error still exits.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66823510/14290681) answer your query?

Answer (score 17):

The problem was solved by uninstalling h5py and installing h5py==2.10.0 as below:

```
pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py==2.10.0
```

If h5py>3, the code shows the error.