# load model error with keras 'str' object has no attribute 'decode

Tags: tensorflow, keras, yolo

I'm doing the deep learing exercise of Andrew Ng,when I try to load the model, it gives the following error:

```
yolo_model = load_model("model_data/yolo.h5")

--> 269         model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
270         model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
271 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode
```

I put the encode() before the decoede() still can not fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, is your issue resolved now? Else, you can try downgrading the verison of h5py as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67327789/14290697) and let us know if the issue still persists.