# google colab tensorflow keras model ran yesterday perfectly but failing today

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, resnet

I am in full and bad surprise. Same program everything is perfect. I just slept and opened the Google colab today to run the program. This is my first ever deep learning program. It ran perfectly yesterday. But when I run today, it is giving a weird error. Need help. Why it is giving such error? How to solve it?
Google colab screenshot:

[image]

Code:

```
  #Step3: test_img_path: Location of the image we want the model to predict
  test_img = image.load_img(test_img_path,target_size=(224,224))
  #Step4: Deep learning models expect a batch of images represented by array
  # At this stage we will have a processed image of size 224x224x3. 
  # Convert it to a batch of images denoted by nx224x224x3 where n denotes total images
  # In this case, n=1
  test_img_array = image.img_to_array(test_img)
  # Convert the array to a batch
  test_img_batch = np.expand_dims(test_img_array,axis=0)  
  #Step5: At the data level, an original image data is stored in the in terms of the pixels. 
  # Now, normalizing the image
  nor_testimg = preprocess_input(test_img_batch)  
  #Step6: Import the model and input our test image
  # Model here means, it is already trained by someone else and I don't have to do it again
  # Moreover, they made their hardwork or trained model freely available to every on on the keras, we just download it
  model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50()  
  #Step7: Lets see how and what the model would predict
  predict_testimg = model.predict(nor_testimg)
  # Decode the predictions
  print(decode_predictions(predict_testimg,top=3)[0])
```

In the above code, `tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50()` is the one causing the problem when I run it today. The same program ran successfully yesterday. Now, if I remove end brackets `tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50`, it runs perfectly but raised an error in the next line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with you and it lies in Keras as its trying to decode a string with utf 8. If I can get some more part of it might be able to help then

Comment: I shared my actual code and the one the causing the problem.

Comment: @Mainland can you also share the version too if thats okay

Comment: I just found the error. I did this last few months but forgot. Now I remember. Here is what I did that solved the issue `pip uninstall h5py
pip install h5py==2.10.0`     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67236747/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-for-tensorflow-in-python   Thanks for your support

Comment: Sure great, nice learning for me too.